# call function from another function in react shows "this.updateTitle is not defined" even when I bind the function in my constructor

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call a function inside of another function. I have binded the only function I am calling inside of the constructor(this.updateTitle) and it still wont get called("function not defined"). I am showing the entire script in case I am missing something crucial from it for why this is happening as this is my first project in react I am making with decent JavaScript experience. If someone could please explain why binding is not working and why my function is not being called, it would be appreciated. Also, an important note is that the functions called from componenetDidMount() WORKS but the other functions I call NOT in componenetDidMount() do NOT WORK. Please control F this.update.title and you will see where they are being called.

```js
//fixed it. this is easier.

import React from 'react';
import '../css/style.css';
import Header from '../header/header';
import Footer from '../footer/footer';

export default class Post extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {

            arr: ["https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/05/19/25/pink-rose-on-empty-swing-3656894_" +
                    "1280.jpg"],

            moveCount: 0,

            title: null,

            body: null
        }

    }

    // choose an image from
    // desktop**********************************************************************
    // * ******************************8

    clickImage = () => {

        document
            .getElementById("submitImage")
            .click();

    }

    // updating
    // state************************************************************************
    // * *****************************************8

    //updtae src title -- update
    updateTitle = (value) => {

        this.setState({title: value});

    }

    //update body -- update
    updateBody = (value) => {

        this.setState({body: value});

    }

    //add source to array -- update
    addSrcArray = (src) => {

        this.setState({
            arr: [
                ...this.state.arr,
                src
            ]
        });

    }

    //remove soure form array -- update
    removeSrcArray = (stateArr, src) => {

        var temp = stateArr;

        temp.splice(temp.indexOf(src), 1);

        this.setState({arr: temp});

    }

    // functions from componenet did mount that updates
    // above************************************************************************
    // * ********************8

    //add the title
    pushTitle = () => {

        var value = document.getElementsByClassName("enterPostTitle")[0].value;

        if (value.length === 0) {

            document.getElementsByClassName("postTitle")[0].innerText = "Title...";

            this.updateTitle(null); //update

            return;

        }

        document.getElementsByClassName("postTitle")[0].innerText = value;

        this.updateTitle(value); //update
    }

    //add the body
    pushBody = () => {

        var value = document.getElementsByClassName("enterPostBody")[0].value;

        if (value.length === 0) {

            document.getElementsByClassName("postBodyContent")[0].innerText = "Body...";

            this.updateBody(null); //update

            return;

        }

        document.getElementsByClassName("postBodyContent")[0].innerText = value;

        this.updateBody(value); //update

    }

    //add the source
    pushSource = (fileUpload) => {

        if (fileUpload.files && fileUpload.files[0] && (fileUpload.files[0].type.toLowerCase() === "image/jpeg" || fileUpload.files[0].type.toLowerCase() === "image/png")) {

            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (e) => {

                if (this.state.arr.includes(e.target.result)) {

                    return;

                }

                this.addSrcArray(e.target.result); //update

                document.getElementsByClassName("postPicture")[0].src = this.state.arr[this.state.arr.length - 1];

                this.state.moveCount = this.state.arr.length - 1;

            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(fileUpload.files[0]);

        }
    }

    //remove the source
    removeSource = (src) => {

        if (this.state.arr.includes(src) && src !== "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/05/19/25/pink-rose-on-empty-swing-3656894_" +
                "1280.jpg") {

            this.removeSrcArray(this.state.arr, src); //update

            this.state.moveCount -= 1;

            document.getElementsByClassName("postPicture")[0].src = this.state.arr[this.state.moveCount];

        }

    }

    //move next and back in source array
    moveBy = (move) => {

        if (this.state.arr.length < 2) {

            return;

        }

        if (move === "next") {

            this.state.moveCount += 1;

            if (this.state.moveCount === this.state.arr.length) {

                this.state.moveCount = 0;

            }

            document.getElementsByClassName("postPicture")[0].src = this.state.arr[this.state.moveCount];

        } else if (move === "back") {

            this.state.moveCount -= 1;

            if (this.state.moveCount === -1) {

                this.state.moveCount = this.state.arr.length - 1

            }

            document.getElementsByClassName("postPicture")[0].src = this.state.arr[this.state.moveCount];

        }

    }

    //check data and push to database
    postDbnnmn = () => {

        var errorArr = [];

        if (this.state.arr === undefined || this.state.arr === null || this.state.arr.length < 1 || this.state.arr.length > 11) {

            errorArr.push("pictureError-only up to 11 pictures allowed");

        }

        if (this.state.body === undefined || this.state.body === null || this.state.body.length > 3000 || this.state.body.length < 15) {

            errorArr.push("bodyError-body must be 15 to 3000 characters");

        }

        if (this.state.title === undefined || this.state.title === null || this.state.title.length > 30 || this.state.title.length < 3) {

            errorArr.push("titleError-title must be 3 and 30 characters");

        }

        if(errorArr.length > 0) {

            errorArr.map(error => {

                document.getElementById(error.split("-")[0]).innerText = errorArr.split("-")[1]; // could do in above but just keeping clean

            })

        } else {

            this.submitForm();

        }

    }

    submitForm = () => {

        //get information and use ajax and submit -- run errors on back

    }

    // on mount listen for
    // events***********************************************************************
    // * ******************************************8
    componentDidMount = () => {

        document
            .getElementById("root")
            .classList
            .add("changeBackground");

        //submit form here using ajax

    }

    render() {

        return (

            <div>

                <Header/>

                <div className="postMain">

                    <div className="postInformation">
                        <h1>Post</h1>
                        <input
                            className="enterPostTitle postFromInfoInput"
                            placeholder="Enter post title"
                            onKeyUp={this.pushTitle}></input>
                        <div>
                            <h1 className="postTitle" hidden>Title...</h1>
                        </div>
                        <textarea
                            rows="12"
                            className="enterPostBody postFromInfoInputB"
                            placeholder="Enter post body"
                            onKeyUp={this.pushBody}></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div className="postBody" hidden>
                        <h2 className="postBodyContent">Body...</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div className="postPictureContent">
                        <input
                            className="enterPostImages postFromInfoInputImage"
                            type="file"
                            id="submitImage"
                            onChange=
                            {(e) => {this.pushSource(e.target)}}
                            hidden></input>
                        <button className="postPictureButton" onClick={this.clickImage}>Add Art</button>
                        <div className="postButtonWrap">
                            <button
                                className="postPictureButton back"
                                onClick=
                                {(e) => {this.moveBy("back")}}>back</button>
                            <button
                                className="postPictureButton next"
                                onClick=
                                {(e) => {this.moveBy("next")}}>next</button>
                        </div>
                        <img
                            className="postPicture"
                            src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/05/19/25/pink-rose-on-empty-swing-3656894_1280.jpg"
                            onClick=
                            {(e) => { this.removeSource(e.target.src) }}></img>
                    </div>

                    <div className="postFormButton">
                        <button className="postButton postFromInfoButton" onClick={this.postDbnnmn}>
                            Post
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <Footer/>

            </div>

        );

    }

}
```

Comment: There's a bizarre amount of low-level hacking around here for a React app. What's the motivation behind all that? React has ways of adding this in without needing to dig around in the DOM directly.

Comment: Tip: When adding an event listener you need to reference a *function* or it will execute immediately. There's a huge difference between `x` and `x(...)`. If you need to make a call with specific arguments, wrap it like: `() => { x(...) }` to make a *deferred* call.

Comment: yes tadman i understand this. thanks for pointing it out though

Comment: Then wrap those function calls to turn them back into functions.

Comment: ok, I will but the main question is why this.update is not being called from specifically the function "pushTitle()". I have tried multiple implementations there at the bottom of the function even without bind(this) but still does not work.

Comment: If you add `debugger` just before calling that does the function exist as you'd expect in that scope?

Comment: and yes, maybe ill just add onclicks in the return function next time instead of componeentDidMount as that would probably work but I didn't really like the look of it so i stuck my listeners in componenetDidMount

Comment: yes the function does get called when it is hit in componeentDodMount but not hit in the other functions I have created

Comment: What you've done there is created a huge mess and I'm not even sure that'd work reliably. React likes to have control over the DOM, so getting in there and monkeying around with it directly is asking for trouble. Let React do that work for you by setting up proper onclick, etc. handlers in your `render()` function.

Comment: I am guessing there is some sort of library function in componenetDidMount that is allowing me to call functions outside of that...just not in my functions

Comment: It's probably just a case of your `this` scope being lost. There's honestly too much code here for me to quickly dig through and identify any specific problem. You'll either have to debug this yourself, or trim it down to a minimal example that produces the exact problem.

Comment: yeah... I mean ok I will do that I guess but it is very nice to see all of the events cleanly laid out in a single function

Comment: "Nice" here is highly subjective. Most React developers are going to run screaming from that function. What's "nice" from a React perspective is having those expressed *in* the actual document you're generating if/when they're needed.

Comment: I forgot to bind my other function.     this.pushTitle = this.pushTitle.bind(this);
    this.updateTitle = this.updateTitle.bind(this);

Comment: i was a calling a bound function from inside a non bound function. So the non bound one could not not read the bound one I am pretty sure.

Comment: A better way to define auto-bound functions is: `updateTitle = (value) => { ... }` where there's no need for the `bind(this)` nonsense.

Comment: it works now but, yeah if I was working with a team sure I would implement that in the component html but to be honest, having all the listeners displayed for you is very easy to work with especially when you are in a large document which you could argue is not the case for react but, it could be. You never know. Imagine having to scroll around for a listener when you already know where it is. And you can just add any functionality within the listener there. But please proceed.

Comment: yes i understand arrow functions bind automatically

Comment: I just mean to say that you can declare them that way in your `class` to avoid all this mess. `x(...) { ... }` vs. `x = (...) => { ... }` can make a huge difference even if it's a tiny change to the source.

Comment: yeah, I am not going to lye I am a very basic programmer. I don't usually use arrow functions but that would be better. Getting the this.bind out of the constructor and just using an arrow function would definitely look and feel better. Yeah I'm definitely going to do that from now on. Thanks for your expertise.

Comment: I had this problem with binding when I started learning React and after switching to arrow functions a lot of issues just went away. Hope that works for you too.

Comment: thanks I appreciate it. I'm done here but if there is a valid reason to add listeners in the html rather than JavaScript I would love to know why. It might look ugly but I would think it would be easier to use in my case. if you want to elaborate. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: At the end of the day this is your code and you can do whatever you want. I'm just suggesting that the *React way* is orthogonal to that.